# How to do reccurent grouping in XSLT

Tags: xslt, group-by

I have the following XML data:

```
<root>
    <Group>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466001">000001</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466002">000002</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466003">000003</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466004">000004</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466005">000005</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466006">000005</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466007">000007</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466008">000008</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466009">000008</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466010">000010</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466001">000003</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466002">000004</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466003">000005</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466006">000007</Line>
    </Group>
</root>
```

I want to have the same group if they have same @PalletID or Line.

Expected result:

```
<root>
    <Group GroupNo="1">
        <Line PalletID="3019379466001">000001</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466001">000003</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466003">000003</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466003">000005</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466005">000005</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466006">000005</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466006">000007</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466007">000007</Line>
    </Group>
    <Group GroupNo="2">
        <Line PalletID="3019379466002">000002</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466002">000004</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466004">000004</Line>
    </Group>
    <Group GroupNo="3">
        <Line PalletID="3019379466008">000008</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466009">000008</Line>
    </Group>
    <Group GroupNo="4">
        <Line PalletID="3019379466010">000010</Line>
    </Group>
</root>
```

I was playing with for-each-group and recurring template but didn't even come close.

Second example of data:

```
<root>
    <Group>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466001">000001</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466002">000004</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466003">000008</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466004">000010</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466005">000017</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466006">000019</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466007">000020</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466008">000021</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466009">000026</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466010">000026</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466011">000028</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466012">000028</Line>
        <Line PalletID="3019379466013">000028</Line>
    </Group>
</root>
```

Expected result: three groups with line 26, 28 and the rest.
The solution should handle around 100 Lines.

Got for that example Error: Too many nested function calls. May be due to infinite recursion

Update:

My environment is Saxon-EE 9.6.0.7
arrays were implemented in Saxon 9.7
Is it possible to avoid using it?

Comment: You want to group by PalletID or by Line number?

Comment: by both of them. If they match they should belong to the same group.

Comment: What XSLT version can you use?

Comment: XSLT version 3.0

Comment: What is wanted output for the second input sample you added? Is that 10 groups where the first eight each containg a single `Line` and the second to last the two `Line`s with content `00026` and the last group three `Line`s with content `00028`?

Comment: Yes, that result is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using keys and recursive functions that seems to give the right output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" 
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all" 
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="pallet" match="Line" use="@PalletID"/>
    <xsl:key name="value" match="Line" use="."/>
    
    <xsl:function name="mf:build-group" as="array(element(Line))">
        <xsl:param name="lines" as="element(Line)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="result" as="array(element(Line))"/>
        
        <xsl:variable name="start-line" select="head($lines)"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$start-line">
                <xsl:variable name="primary-group"
                    select="key('pallet', $start-line/@PalletID, root($start-line))"/>
                <xsl:variable name="secondary-group"
                    select="key('value', $primary-group, root($primary-group[1])) except ($result?*, $primary-group)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="head-result"
                    select="array:join(($result, mf:build-group($secondary-group, array {$primary-group})))"/>
                <xsl:sequence select="$head-result"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="mf:build-groups" as="array(element(Line))*">
        <xsl:param name="lines" as="element(Line)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="result" as="array(element(Line))*"/>

        <xsl:variable name="start-line" select="head($lines)"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$start-line">
                <xsl:variable name="head-result" select="mf:build-group($start-line, [])"/>
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:build-groups(tail($lines) except ($result?*, $head-result?*), ($result, $head-result))"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="Group">
        <xsl:iterate select="mf:build-groups(Line, ())">
            <Group GroupNo="{position()}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="?*"/>
            </Group>
        </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9M

In https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9M/2 I have replaced one of the functions with `xsl:iterate` and used more general and hopefully descriptive key names:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" 
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all" 
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="primary" match="Line" use="@PalletID"/>
    <xsl:key name="secondary" match="Line" use="."/>
    
    <xsl:function name="mf:build-group" as="array(element(Line))">
        <xsl:param name="lines" as="element(Line)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="result" as="array(element(Line))"/>
        
        <xsl:variable name="start-line" select="head($lines)"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($start-line)">
                <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable 
                    name="primary-group"
                    select="key('primary', $start-line/@PalletID, root($start-line))"/>
                <xsl:variable 
                    name="secondary-group"
                    select="key('secondary', $primary-group, root($primary-group[1])) except ($result?*, $primary-group)"/>
                <xsl:sequence 
                    select="array:join(($result, mf:build-group($secondary-group, array {$primary-group})))"/>                
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="Group">
        <xsl:iterate select="Line">
            <xsl:param name="groups" as="array(element(Line))*" select="()"/>
            <xsl:on-completion>
                <xsl:iterate select="$groups">
                    <Group GroupNo="{position()}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="?*"/>
                    </Group>
                </xsl:iterate>
            </xsl:on-completion>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=". intersect $groups?*">
                    <xsl:next-iteration/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:next-iteration>
                        <xsl:with-param name="groups" select="$groups, mf:build-group(., [])"/>
                    </xsl:next-iteration>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following adaption of the second suggestion seems to handle both the first and second input sample, if I understand the requirements correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" 
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all" 
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:key name="primary" match="Line" use="@PalletID"/>
    <xsl:key name="secondary" match="Line" use="."/>
    
    <xsl:function name="mf:build-group" as="element(Line)*">
        <xsl:param name="lines" as="element(Line)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="result" as="element(Line)*"/>
        
        <xsl:variable name="start-line" select="head($lines)"/>
        
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($start-line)">
                <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable 
                    name="primary-group"
                    select="key('primary', $start-line/@PalletID, root($start-line))"/>
                <xsl:variable name="current-result" select="$result | $primary-group"/>
                <xsl:variable 
                    name="secondary-group"
                    select="key('secondary', $primary-group, root($primary-group[1])) except $current-result"/>
                <xsl:sequence 
                    select="mf:build-group($secondary-group, $current-result)"/>                
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:template match="Group">
        <xsl:iterate select="Line">
            <xsl:param name="groups" as="array(element(Line))*" select="()"/>
            <xsl:on-completion>
                <xsl:iterate select="$groups">
                    <Group GroupNo="{position()}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="?*"/>
                    </Group>
                </xsl:iterate>
            </xsl:on-completion>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=". intersect $groups?*">
                    <xsl:next-iteration/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:next-iteration>
                        <xsl:with-param name="groups" select="$groups, array { mf:build-group(., ()) }"/>
                    </xsl:next-iteration>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9M/6

Comment: Thank you, this is code which I can work with. I added one more example of data, where I get Error: Too many nested function calls. May be due to infinite recursion

Comment: @AndreyDavydenko, let me know whether the third suggestion does what you want. I will then remove the first two ones from the answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Links doesn't work, but I got the correct results on 100 lines in https://xslttest.appspot.com/ Now I'm trying to use it in my environment with Saxon EE 9.6.0.7

Comment: Is it possible to avoid using arrays? They were introduced in Saxon 9.7, but my version is Saxon 9.6.0.7

Comment: @AndreyDavydenko, I think you originally stated you can use XSLT version 3, the first Saxon release to implement XSLT 3 is 9.8. I am afraid I am not in a mood to try to figure which parts of XSLT 3 support in 9.6 were compatible with the final spec released in 2017 and implemented in 9.8 and later. On the other hand the last sample only uses arrays as a light-weight wrapper to contain a group, you could use an XML wrapper element. But I can't judge whether `xsl:iterate` was supported the same way or whether there can be other incompatibilities.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, will try to figure out how to add XML wrapper instead of array.

Comment: @AndreyDavydenko, I have managed to avoid the use of the array container at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9M/8 although I had to change the approach a bit to output the latest group while iterating and to store a flat sequence of Line elements in the iterator parameter as otherwise, with a newly constructed XML wrapper, the `intersect` would not work.

Comment: big thank you for your efforts! The last solution works smoothly in my envorinment! :-)